# How to add comment to a test case while marking it pass/fail via api in VSTS through SopaUI

Tags: soapui, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to add comment to my test result but I don't see any parameter in the JSON to do so though I am able to post the rest Pass/Fail from below JSON:

Method:
 **POST**

Request url: `https://dev.azure.com/{organisation}/{project}/_api/_testManagement/BulkMarkTestPoints`

JSON:

```
{"planId":1455039,"suiteId":1455040,"testPointIds":[3853222],"outcome":2}
```

I explored the api's and found that there is an api to update using PATH method on the result id, but that is not suitable as we'll have to first run the case then fetch the lastresult id and then update against that result id.

Comment: It would be great if anyone can look into it.

Comment: I’ve read this post a few times now and I’m really not sure what you are trying to achieve.  Can you expand your question?

Comment: I am trying to post comment along with the status(pass/fail) in the test case against the point id. I don't see any direct API available to do so. 1 API I found, it's used to update the result using PATCH method against the result id, and it's not suitable in my case.

Comment: @Bharat What do you mean `How to add comment` ? Are you intend to check the response after executing the test if the test is `passed` or `failed` ?

Comment: @royki **Yes**  I Intend to check the response after completion of the **execution** , in both the cases(pass/fail) response should also be posted in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Not so clear about the question. Tried to answer after reading the comments.

Normally you can add assertion from SoapUI feature.

Add assertion of `Valid HTTP Status Codes` - `201` as it is `POST` method. (Assume This `POST` ll return `201`;(On success Case - depending on the development it might return `200` status code as well)

You can check the `Response` body with SoapUI assertion feature.

By Groovy Script - 
If You want to check the `Response` status code as well as Response body

```
import groovy.json.*
import com.eviware.soapui.support.JsonUtil

def teststep = "Your_REST_TEST_Step_Name"
def request = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName(teststep)
def headers = request.testRequest.response.responseHeaders
// Check the Response Body
def response = request.getPropertyValue("Response")
def JsResponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)

// Actual Response 
def actualHTTPResponse = headers['#status#']

// Expected Response
def expectedHTTPResponse = ['HTTP/1.1 201 Created'] // or ['HTTP/1.1 200 OK'] 

assert actualHTTPResponse == expectedHTTPResponse:"Test Step Failed"

// For Response Body
assert !JsResponse.isEmpty() ==  true
// Check if the response schema has elements or not !!! 
assert JsResponse.inspect().contains("planId") == true
..................................................
..................................................
// You can do different type of checking depending on your requirement.
```

PS: There are lot of reasons of failing like - `4xx - 401 - Authentication Error`, `409`, `400`. `5xx - 500 Internal server error` etc. Now What kind of Failed case you have, depending on that you can do some assertion from SoapUI or Groovy Script.